# use two group by in one mongodb query to match expected result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, mongodb-query, document

I have two documents (item and room) and I want to get the data as structured below :

```
SELECT date, items, room
FROM itemsDocs
JOIN roomDocs ON itemsDocs.room = roomDocs._id
group by room
group by item.date
```

This is the query I tried for now :

```
let agg=[
        { $lookup: { 
            from: 'item', 
            localField: '_id', 
            foreignField: 'room', 
            as: 'data' }},
        {
            $unwind: { path: "$item", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
        },
          {
            $sort:{
                date:1
            }
        },
        {$group:{
                _id: "$_id", 
            room: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
            },
        },
        {$project:{
            room:1,
            data:1,
        }}
    ]
```

The result of this query was an array of distinct rooms each one have list of items :

```
[
    {
     room: ...
     items: [...]
    },
    ...
]
```

expected result :

```
[
{
 date: ...
 room: ...
 items: [...]
},
...
]
```

How can I get this result with mongoDb ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to update the model/class here too. Otherwise its difficult to look into the question

Comment: for join use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and for group use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)